# Laravel 5 multiple attach

Tags: laravel, relationship, foreign-key-relationship

I Have table with 3 ID from other columns. How to Attach more than 2 ID? I 
dont know how to Attach thoes three keys. When I try to do "  $weather->parks()->attach('1')->users()->attach('2');" it don't attach park_id.
Please Help.

```
Schema::create('weather_user_park', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->integer('weather_id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('park_id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('weather_id')->references('id')->on('weathers');
        $table->foreign('park_id')->references('id')->on('parks');
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
    });
```

I also have 3 Models:

**Park.php**

```
public function weathers()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Weather', 'weather_user_park');
}

    public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'weather_user_park');
}
```

**User.php**

```
public function weathers()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Weather', 'weather_user_park');
}

    public function parks()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Park', 'weather_user_park');
}
```

**Weather.php**

```
       public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'weather_user_park');
}

    public function parks()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Park', 'weather_user_park');
}
```

Comment: have you tried not chaining the methods that way? and just call it separately?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Park.php**

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'park_user')->withPivot('weather');
}
```

**User.php**

```
public function parks()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Park', 'park_user')->withPivot('weather');
}
```

`park->users();` gives you information for the park

you can add info to a user like so:

```
$park = App\Park::find(1);
$weather = App\Weather::find($id);
$user->parks()->attach($park->id, ['weather' => $weather->id]);
```

to remove the relationship

```
$user->parks()->detach($park->id);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by adding second parameter to attach method.

```
$weather->parks()->attach(1, [
    'user_id' => 2,
]);
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships
https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many (especially "Retrieving Intermediate Table Columns" section)